# Why adapter.setDataNotifyChange only work when I scroll view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use `RecyclerView` to display my list, when I change data in list and then I call `adapter.setDataNotifyChange`, nothing change.

But when I scrolled `RecyclerView`, data has been changed.

I don't know why. How can I fix it? I want `RecyclerView` change as soon as I change data in list.

Comment: post your code please. where are you updating data?

Comment: @firegloves my project has 3 class: main activity, recycler adapter and recycler view holder. I update data in main. I cannot explain why adapter  doesnt notify data change ulti I sroll view.

Comment: yeah but without code I can't see anything, i'm not a wizard ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Recyclerview update when you scroll because the event of "onBindViewHolder" will be called for every position available to the View.

The **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged** will notify any registered observers that the data set has changed.[1]

The **adapter.notifyItemChanged** will notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed.[1]

Can you post your code?

[1]https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html